# Getting error as 'TypeError: results.map is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React code, when trying to map the results of API I'am unable to get the data. Here is the code for reference.

1. App.js

```
export const AdminPanel = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [results, setResults] = useState([])

  const profileData = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
        setResults(res)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    profileData()
}, [])

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>First Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Last Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Address</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Photo</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Email</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">DOB</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>

            {results.map((person) => {
                console.log('PERSON', person)
            })}

        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Even though declared results as Array, still gives error. Am I mistaking somewhere.
What could be appropriate solution?

Comment: can you console log results and share

Comment: After console.log its showing first [] and then all the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Your axios call needs to change a bit. Here is how to fix it:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [results, setResults] = React.useState([]);

  const profileData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios
        .get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10")
        .then((result) => result.data.results);
      setResults(res)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    profileData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      {results.map((person) => {
        console.log("PERSON", person);
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note this part:

```
const res = await axios
        .get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10")
        .then((result) => result.data.results);
```

Also keep in mind that `console.log("PERSON", person);` inside your return function will not actually render anything on the page, it's going to print to the console. Just wanted to make that clear.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-shockley-9m5vj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

setResults(res.results) should do the job